# Find capitalised lowercase string and put before uppercase string

Tags: string

I have a bash script reading names from a webpage as variables, which use the format LASTNAME Firstname:

```
SANCHEZ Rick
SMITH Morty
VAN SOMETHING Halen
```

However, I need to display each name as Firstname LASTNAME:

```
Rick SANCHEZ
Morty SMITH
Halen VAN SOMETHING
```

I am looking for a way to recognize the lowercase capitalised first name and put it before the uppercase last name or names.

The closest I got was

```
echo $eachname | awk '{ for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf("%s ",$i); print $1; }'
```

This command however messes up people with two last names:

```
Rick SANCHEZ
Morty SMITH
Halen SOMETHING VAN
```

Comment: Can you assume that the last word in the line is the first name? Or do we have things like SMITH Jim Bob

Comment: Indeed, the last word is always the first name.

Comment: Perhaps it is simpler to strip out the last word and put it in the first position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a `sed` possibility, given two or more last names and first names:

```
SANCHEZ Rick Ignatius Alexander
SMITH Morty
FOO VAN SOMETHING Halen
```

The command;

```
sed 's/^\([^a-z]*\)[[:blank:]]\(.*\)$/\2 \1/' file
```

Output:

```
Rick Ignatius Alexander SANCHEZ
Morty SMITH
Halen FOO VAN SOMETHING
```

Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: @bu5hman Yeah, I escaped the `(` but forgot to delete the `-E`, fixed, thanks.

Comment: This works perfectly. I cannot upvote you because I have a new account, apparently, but thank you very much!

Comment: @NilsDeschrijver You can mark it as answered :). Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Or an alternative `sed` keeping middle names at the end

This input

```
SANCHEZ Rick
SMITH Morty
VAN SOMETHING Halen
MCSMITH Some Body
```

With this

```
sed -E "s/^([A-Z ]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)(.*)/\2 \1\3/" file1
```

Gives this output

```
Rick SANCHEZ
Morty SMITH
Halen VAN SOMETHING
Some MCSMITH Body
```